# UITableview is not updated in background-transfer-service-ios7/

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using the [code from here](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/) to download mp3 files.  I have copied the code to my one of my view controller and it is working fine. However, progress view is not updated (i.e. UI is not updated / UI Thread is not working) after I press ‘Back’ button and come back to the view again.  I am new to iOS.  Any help is much appreciated.

UI is updated in

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{
```

The complete code as follows

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  BGTransferDemo
//
//  Created by Gabriel Theodoropoulos on 25/3/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Appcoda. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FileDownloadInfo.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


// Define some constants regarding the tag values of the prototype cell's subviews.
#define CellLabelTagValue               10
#define CellStartPauseButtonTagValue    20
#define CellStopButtonTagValue          30
#define CellProgressBarTagValue         40
#define CellLabelReadyTagValue          50


@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrFileDownloadData;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *docDirectoryURL;


-(void)initializeFileDownloadDataArray;
-(int)getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:(unsigned long)taskIdentifier;

@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    [self initializeFileDownloadDataArray];

    NSArray *URLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    self.docDirectoryURL = [URLs objectAtIndex:0];


    // Make self the delegate and datasource of the table view.
    self.tblFiles.delegate = self;
    self.tblFiles.dataSource = self;

    // Disable scrolling in table view.
    self.tblFiles.scrollEnabled = NO;


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.BGTransferDemo"];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 5;


    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration
                                                 delegate:self
                                            delegateQueue:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Private method implementation

-(void)initializeFileDownloadDataArray{
    self.arrFileDownloadData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:@"iOS Programming Guide" andDownloadSource:@"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf"]];
    [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:@"Human Interface Guidelines" andDownloadSource:@"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/MobileHIG.pdf"]];
    [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:@"Networking Overview" andDownloadSource:@"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/NetworkingOverview.pdf"]];
    [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:@"AV Foundation" andDownloadSource:@"https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/AVFoundationPG.pdf"]];
    [self.arrFileDownloadData addObject:[[FileDownloadInfo alloc] initWithFileTitle:@"iPhone User Guide" andDownloadSource:@"http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf"]];
}


-(int)getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:(unsigned long)taskIdentifier{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<[self.arrFileDownloadData count]; i++) {
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:i];
        if (fdi.taskIdentifier == taskIdentifier) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return index;
}


#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate and Datasource method implementation

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.arrFileDownloadData.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"idCell"];
    }

    // Get the respective FileDownloadInfo object from the arrFileDownloadData array.
    FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Get all cell's subviews.
    UILabel *displayedTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    UIButton *startPauseButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:CellStartPauseButtonTagValue];
    UIButton *stopButton = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:CellStopButtonTagValue];
    UIProgressView *progressView = (UIProgressView *)[cell viewWithTag:CellProgressBarTagValue];
    UILabel *readyLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:CellLabelReadyTagValue];

    NSString *startPauseButtonImageName;

    // Set the file title.
    displayedTitle.text = fdi.fileTitle;

    // Depending on whether the current file is being downloaded or not, specify the status
    // of the progress bar and the couple of buttons on the cell.
    if (!fdi.isDownloading) {
        // Hide the progress view and disable the stop button.
        progressView.hidden = YES;
        stopButton.enabled = NO;

        // Set a flag value depending on the downloadComplete property of the fdi object.
        // Using it will be shown either the start and stop buttons, or the Ready label.
        BOOL hideControls = (fdi.downloadComplete) ? YES : NO;
        startPauseButton.hidden = hideControls;
        stopButton.hidden = hideControls;
        readyLabel.hidden = !hideControls;

        startPauseButtonImageName = @"play-25";
    }
    else{
        // Show the progress view and update its progress, change the image of the start button so it shows
        // a pause icon, and enable the stop button.
        progressView.hidden = NO;
        progressView.progress = fdi.downloadProgress;

        stopButton.enabled = YES;

        startPauseButtonImageName = @"pause-25";
    }

    // Set the appropriate image to the start button.
    [startPauseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:startPauseButtonImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return cell;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 60.0;
}


#pragma mark - IBAction method implementation

- (IBAction)startOrPauseDownloadingSingleFile:(id)sender {
    // Check if the parent view of the sender button is a table view cell.
    if ([[[sender superview] superview] isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        // Get the container cell.
        UITableViewCell *containerCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];

        // Get the row (index) of the cell. We'll keep the index path as well, we'll need it later.
        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tblFiles indexPathForCell:containerCell];
        int cellIndex = cellIndexPath.row;

        // Get the FileDownloadInfo object being at the cellIndex position of the array.
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:cellIndex];

        // The isDownloading property of the fdi object defines whether a downloading should be started
        // or be stopped.
        if (!fdi.isDownloading) {
            // This is the case where a download task should be started.

            // Create a new task, but check whether it should be created using a URL or resume data.
            if (fdi.taskIdentifier == -1) {
                // If the taskIdentifier property of the fdi object has value -1, then create a new task
                // providing the appropriate URL as the download source.
                fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fdi.downloadSource]];

                // Keep the new task identifier.
                fdi.taskIdentifier = fdi.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;

                // Start the task.
                [fdi.downloadTask resume];
            }
            else{
                // Create a new download task, which will use the stored resume data.
                fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithResumeData:fdi.taskResumeData];
                [fdi.downloadTask resume];

                // Keep the new download task identifier.
                fdi.taskIdentifier = fdi.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;
            }
        }
        else{
            // Pause the task by canceling it and storing the resume data.
            [fdi.downloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData:^(NSData *resumeData) {
                if (resumeData != nil) {
                    fdi.taskResumeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:resumeData];
                }
            }];
        }

        // Change the isDownloading property value.
        fdi.isDownloading = !fdi.isDownloading;

        // Reload the table view.
        [self.tblFiles reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}


- (IBAction)stopDownloading:(id)sender {
    if ([[[sender superview] superview] isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        // Get the container cell.
        UITableViewCell *containerCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];

        // Get the row (index) of the cell. We'll keep the index path as well, we'll need it later.
        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tblFiles indexPathForCell:containerCell];
        int cellIndex = cellIndexPath.row;

        // Get the FileDownloadInfo object being at the cellIndex position of the array.
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:cellIndex];

        // Cancel the task.
        [fdi.downloadTask cancel];

        // Change all related properties.
        fdi.isDownloading = NO;
        fdi.taskIdentifier = -1;
        fdi.downloadProgress = 0.0;

        // Reload the table view.
        [self.tblFiles reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}


- (IBAction)startAllDownloads:(id)sender {
    // Access all FileDownloadInfo objects using a loop.
    for (int i=0; i<[self.arrFileDownloadData count]; i++) {
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:i];

        // Check if a file is already being downloaded or not.
        if (!fdi.isDownloading) {
            // Check if should create a new download task using a URL, or using resume data.
            if (fdi.taskIdentifier == -1) {
                fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fdi.downloadSource]];
            }
            else{
                fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithResumeData:fdi.taskResumeData];
            }

            // Keep the new taskIdentifier.
            fdi.taskIdentifier = fdi.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;

            // Start the download.
            [fdi.downloadTask resume];

            // Indicate for each file that is being downloaded.
            fdi.isDownloading = YES;
        }
    }

    // Reload the table view.
    [self.tblFiles reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)stopAllDownloads:(id)sender {
    // Access all FileDownloadInfo objects using a loop.
    for (int i=0; i<[self.arrFileDownloadData count]; i++) {
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:i];

        // Check if a file is being currently downloading.
        if (fdi.isDownloading) {
            // Cancel the task.
            [fdi.downloadTask cancel];

            // Change all related properties.
            fdi.isDownloading = NO;
            fdi.taskIdentifier = -1;
            fdi.downloadProgress = 0.0;
            fdi.downloadTask = nil;
        }
    }

    // Reload the table view.
    [self.tblFiles reloadData];
}


- (IBAction)initializeAll:(id)sender {
    // Access all FileDownloadInfo objects using a loop and give all properties their initial values.
    for (int i=0; i<[self.arrFileDownloadData count]; i++) {
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:i];

        if (fdi.isDownloading) {
            [fdi.downloadTask cancel];
        }

        fdi.isDownloading = NO;
        fdi.downloadComplete = NO;
        fdi.taskIdentifier = -1;
        fdi.downloadProgress = 0.0;
        fdi.downloadTask = nil;
    }

    // Reload the table view.
    [self.tblFiles reloadData];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get all files in documents directory.
    NSArray *allFiles = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:self.docDirectoryURL
                                   includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                                                      options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                        error:nil];
    for (int i=0; i<[allFiles count]; i++) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:[allFiles objectAtIndex:i] error:nil];
    }
}


#pragma mark - NSURLSession Delegate method implementation

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *destinationFilename = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent;
    NSURL *destinationURL = [self.docDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:destinationFilename];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationURL path]]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:nil];
    }

    BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location
                                        toURL:destinationURL
                                        error:&error];

    if (success) {
        // Change the flag values of the respective FileDownloadInfo object.
        int index = [self getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:downloadTask.taskIdentifier];
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:index];

        fdi.isDownloading = NO;
        fdi.downloadComplete = YES;

        // Set the initial value to the taskIdentifier property of the fdi object,
        // so when the start button gets tapped again to start over the file download.
        fdi.taskIdentifier = -1;

        // In case there is any resume data stored in the fdi object, just make it nil.
        fdi.taskResumeData = nil;

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // Reload the respective table view row using the main thread.
            [self.tblFiles reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        }];

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Unable to copy temp file. Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Download completed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Download finished successfully.");
    }
}


-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

    if (totalBytesExpectedToWrite == NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"Unknown transfer size");
    }
    else{
        // Locate the FileDownloadInfo object among all based on the taskIdentifier property of the task.
        int index = [self getFileDownloadInfoIndexWithTaskIdentifier:downloadTask.taskIdentifier];
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:index];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // Calculate the progress.
            fdi.downloadProgress = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

            // Get the progress view of the appropriate cell and update its progress.
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblFiles cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
            UIProgressView *progressView = (UIProgressView *)[cell viewWithTag:CellProgressBarTagValue];
            progressView.progress = fdi.downloadProgress;
        }];
    }
}


-(void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    // Check if all download tasks have been finished.
    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {

        if ([downloadTasks count] == 0) {
            if (appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler != nil) {
                // Copy locally the completion handler.
                void(^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler;

                // Make nil the backgroundTransferCompletionHandler.
                appDelegate.backgroundTransferCompletionHandler = nil;

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    // Call the completion handler to tell the system that there are no other background transfers.
                    completionHandler();

                    // Show a local notification when all downloads are over.
                    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                    localNotification.alertBody = @"All files have been downloaded!";
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you updating the views in the completion handler of the NSURLSession? If so, try updating them on the main thread as all UI elements need to be updated on the main thread.

Comment: Also, you might need to save the status of the progress bar when the view is about to disappear. You can do this in viewWillDisappear{}.

Comment: Yes, It is updated in the main thread in [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ ...    It is ok if the progress view of the current download is not updated. But, Progress View is not updated for new downloads also after I press Back button and come back to the view.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I see what you mean now - I'll see if I can figure it out. (Just a side note, adding an operation to the [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] does not guarantee that the block will be called immediately. It will run on the main thread but you have no idea when. If you want it to be called immediately you should use performSelectorOnMainThread: and make sure that waitUntilDone is set to YES.)

Comment: it is working fine. After I add  - (void)viewWillDisappear {  [session invalidateAndCancel] } .   Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why progress is not working, because you need to remember which items are started downloading, and again create respective downloading tasks and call resume on that tasks.

To avoid from this situation, you need to separate downloading logic into different class, for example you can create DownloadManager class, that will initiate download and give feedback about progress,completion,error. DownloadManager can be singleton, so you can access downloading progress from anywhere.

**UPDATE**
Here is the link to the example:
https://github.com/hovox/downloading-file-example

Comment: It is ok if the progress view of the current download is not updated. But, Progress View is not updated even for new downloads also after I press Back button and come back to the view.  Somehow, the main thread/main queue is not responding to the update of view.  fyi, Progress view is updated in the function -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

Comment: Anyway if you do changes like I'm said, it should be ok. I can create some example project with DownloadManager class if you want.

Comment: would appreciate if you could share the example project. Thanks. As for the code above, it is work fine and the files are downloaded even in the second run (ie. after I press Back button and come back to the view). But the progress view is not working in the subsequent download though the file is downloaded in the background.

Comment: it is working fine. After I add - (void)viewWillDisappear { [session invalidateAndCancel] } .   Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was busy in last week, I have updated my answer with the link to the example project. Buy the way if you call [session invalidateAndCancel] then download will start from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Tested ok. It is a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, if you think that it's the right answer, can you mark as a right answer please ? Thanks.